# How to call this function from other activities?

Tags: android, function, kotlin, android-activity

i need help in this kotlin code pls ... i have checkConnctivvity() function and it's working perfectly ...

```
fun checkConnectivity(){

    val cm=getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val activeNetwork =cm.activeNetworkInfo
    val isConnected=activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting}
```

1/ i tried different ways to call it from  other activities but i couldn't ... How to solve it plz

2/ i want to add the checkConnectivity() function in webChromeClient  , so each time the progressBarChanged it will verify the connection .. but didn't worked

```
class ExodyaActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exodya)

    //Problem1: failed to call the checkConnectivity() from MainActivity

    val myWebview   = ExoWeb
    var ProgressBar = progressBar
    var FrameLayout = frameLayout
    var TextView  = loadPrs

    myWebview.visibility = View.GONE
    frameLayout.visibility = View.GONE
    loadLinear.visibility = View.GONE

    //webview
    myWebview.webViewClient= WebViewClient()
    myWebview.settings.javaScriptEnabled=true
    myWebview.loadUrl("url")

    ProgressBar.max = 100

    myWebview.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
        override fun onProgressChanged(view: WebView, progress: Int) {

            // Problem2: checkConnectivity()  didn't work here !!!!

            progressBar.progress = progress
            if(progress < 90) {
                loadPrs.text = " %" + progress
                myWebview.visibility = View.GONE
                frameLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                loadLinear.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            if (progress == 100) {

                FrameLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                loadLinear.visibility = View.GONE
                myWebview.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
    }

}
// onBackPressed (back in webview history)
 override fun onBackPressed() {
     var myWebview   = ExoWeb
    if (myWebview.canGoBack()) {
        myWebview.goBack()
    } else {
         super.onBackPressed()
            Toast.makeText(this,"See You Next Time!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
             }
        }

}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create Kotlin file, e.g. named `Utils`;
2. Move function to that file, and add `Context` parameter:

   ```
   fun checkConnectivity(ctx: Context): Boolean {
       val cm = ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
       val activeNetwork =cm.activeNetworkInfo
       return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting
   }
   ```

   If you intend to use it only in `Activity` you can create extension function without `Context` parameter:

   ```
   fun Activity.checkConnectivity(): Boolean {
       val cm = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
       val activeNetwork =cm.activeNetworkInfo
       return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting
   }
   ```
3. Call that function from wherever you want. If you call it from `Activity` just use code:

   ```
   checkConnectivity(this@YourActivity)
   ```

   If you created extension function, just call it in `Activity` without passing any parameters:

   ```
   checkConnectivity()
   ```

Comment: ty for your help ... i did create a kt file ... and i call it from an other activity ... but when i try to use it , show me error (unresolved reference:isConnected) :    if (isConnected){
             var intent=Intent(this,ExodyaActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }

Comment: can you plz help in this one too ... and ty

Comment: In my answer I don't use `isConnected` variable. Looking to your question, I see you are using it in `checkConnectivity` function. Just add it to the function if you want to use it, but I don't see the reason: the function is already returns status whether network connected or not. The code to add: `val isConnected=activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting`.